# Game featuring a superhero duck in red and blue with a gun

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember that I used to play a PC game with my cousin when we were kids (late 90s / early 2000s), and we were trying to find it again, but no success because we can't remember its name.

Here are some characteristics that we remembered:

- 2D platform game
- Levels had different scenarios (like a forest, a haunted castle, Egypt and outer space)
- Main character was a duck
- Duck's clothes were blue and red
- Duck had a gun (maybe a laser gun)
- Enemies included flowers, zombies, aliens
- Publisher was maybe eGames or EA Games (don't know for sure)

We had the CD to install the game, but apparently we lost it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This might be the 1996 game [*Crazy Drake*](https://obscuritory.com/platform/crazy-drake/).  The hero is a duck dressed in red-and-blue and he has a purple gun, fights aliens:

[image: The hero Prince Drake fires his gun at a flying UFO piloted by a green alien with eyes on stalks.]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Drake) it was released by eGames.